# HTML5 AUDIO tag not working in Opera

Tags: html, audio, mp3, opera, ogg

I discovered what appears to be a bug in Opera where it will not play an audio file. The play button is disabled and the volume has a mark through it. I've tested on IE, FireFox, Chrome and Safari and the audio file plays perfectly. There are no answers to this problem I could find anywhere that actually work.
The files OGG, WAV, & MP3 play perfectly alone as well, so I'm 100% sure the files are good and the paths are good too (if the paths weren't correct, the other browsers would not play).

What's the secret magic trick to get Opera to actually support HTML5 AUDIO tags?
Here is a test snippet that works in everything I can throw at it (except Opera - any version)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>


    <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/SEGMENT_1_MINI_LOTS.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        <source src="audio/SEGMENT_1_MINI_LOTS.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>   
        <source src="audio/SEGMENT_1_MINI_LOTS.wav" type="audio/wav"/> 
        Please upgrade your browser.
    </audio>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/audio the `<audio>` is supported since version `9.0`, that's 17 versions back

Comment: I saw that chart, the player shows up, just won't play the files.  I'm thinking it doesn't support ogg, mp3 or wav formats or their sub formats (sampling/resolution).

Comment: What is the result of `document.querySelector('audio').error.code` ?

Comment: I just installed Opera, created a sample file on localhost it worked fine, and added `autoplay` attribute to make auto play the file ...

Comment: what file format? ogg? what's the sampling rate?

Comment: I loaded an OGG from my DropBox, while i left the other 2 formats as same (your code) so they will fail to load.

Comment: TypeError: document.querySelector(...).error is null

Comment: so it only supports OGG - okay, that's cool, I'm going to convert to every version of ogg until 1 version works (hopefully).

Comment: Opera does not support 320x48 OGG!

Comment: OK - Opera works with 192x44, 128x44 and 48x22 OGG subformats. 
192x44 is 192Kbps, 44Khz for those who need this info

Answer (score 3):

Opera does NOT support 320Kbps / 48kHz audio formats.

Opera only works with 192x44, 128x44 and 48x22 OGG subformats.